# Send email from aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I am currently creating a CONTACT US page to my user. Here, users can send to me email from any email.

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = dlg.FileName;

        try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

            mail.From = new MailAddress(TextBox1.Text);
            mail.To.Add("u@urdomain.com");
            mail.Subject = filename;
            mail.Body = "Report";
            Attachment attachment = new Attachment(filename);
            mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

            SmtpServer.Port = 25;
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("me", "password");
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
        }
```

This email only be received from gmail account. How to receive email-from yahoo,hotmail,ect? and for this part `SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("me", "password");` what should i write? How to get user's password and mail? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send from the user's email address.

Instead, you need to send from one address you own (and use its username & password & STMP server) to a different address that you own.

Answer (score 0):

`smtp.gmail.com` is not a public SMTP server. It is reserved for gmail users to send and receive mail.

Most SMTP servers are restricted to send mail only from users in its domain and receive mail only for users in its domain. In short, you can not use smtp.gmail.com to send mail from joe@aol.com to pete@msn.com.

You can resolve your problem in one of two ways:

1. Your users can click on a `mailto` link on your page. That will result in the user sending you mail from their default mail client through their ISP. The drawback of this approach is that you'll have to jump through a few hoops to prevent spam.
2. You can install an SMTP server on your server and change your application to use that server. Because that server will be accepting emails from/to email addresses in a domain other than its own, you must ensure that this SMTP server is not accessible on the open internet. Otherwise, spammers will use your server as an open relay.